# Jquery check if special char exists in text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to check if a textarea contains some special characters, so i need to count them 2 (SMS lenght).

I wrote this piece of code but seems that it doesn't find no special chars, also if write only "€€€"

Could you please help me? Also if you would to rewrite directly function, without problem. Thank tou!

```
var SPECIAL_CHARS   = Array('€', '%');

function charUsed() {
    var count                   = $('#text').val().length;
    var chars                   = $('#text').val().split("");
    var numberOfSpecialChars    = 0;
    if ($.inArray(chars, SPECIAL_CHARS) > -1) {
        numberOfSpecialChars++;
    }
    return count + numberOfSpecialChars;
} // function
```

Comment: sorry to ask, but if you check for existance of any special-char, why not use regex?

Comment: `$.inArray` takes `value`, `array`, not two arrays.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker Solved with for (var k=0; k<chars.length; k++) {
  if ($.inArray(chars[k], SPECIAL_CHARS) > -1) {
   numberOfSpecialChars++;
  }
 }

Comment: @sineverba if you like your solution, post it as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KSm7J/

```
var chars = $('#text').val().match(/[€%]/g).length;
alert(chars);
```

Comment: Damn... this is simpler than mine... +1

Answer (score 3):

A rewrite :

```
var nbSpecialChars = $('#text').val().split(/[€%]/).length - 1;
```

The idea is to make an array of strings, using your special characters as separator :

```
'some € chars %' => ["some ", " chars ", ""]
```

and then use the length of this array to deduce the count of those chars. There are many other (faster) solutions but this one is short.

Comment: aaaand he understands what you did.... not... please be so kind to illuminate your answer, and what you did to OP